# Why does the shopping cart display the login form?

Tags: 8, users, commerce

When I'm not logged in and click on the cart logo, the following page appears with the login form:

```
/cart
```

1) I want the contents of the shopping cart to be displayed.

2) When I click on the "Checkout" button I want to display the login form.

How to do this ?

Why does the shopping cart display the login form ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a a few ways.
1) Set permission to access cart to logged in users only 
2) On site information page, set 403 to user/login

There should be a module for this. As soon as I find it, I will update my answer.

[image]

Comment: This feature is already installed on my site. Why the anonymous user can not view the contents of the shopping cart?

Comment: You didn't mention that. Did the user added any item to shopping cart? Be specific about your query

Comment: Yes it has an item in the shopping cart, even without item, it should have a message "Your shopping cart is empty". Here is one of my products https://www.s1biose.com/produit/savon-artisanal-bio-la-cannelle

Comment: You need to check permissions. Also, make sure visitors can buy from the site.

Comment: I added the screenshots of my configuration to my question

Comment: Have a look at this: http://bit.ly/DrupalTR

Comment: Make sure, there are no other modules/permissions are overriding the cart access configurations/permissions

Comment: On the link I shared, there is a add to cart button. Give it a try.

Comment: I checked the permissions and it is correctly configured. I use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_marketplace

Comment: I checked with your website and I guess, it is the cart permissions that you have to check with. Make sure users have 'Access Checkout' permissions:

Check the screen shot I attached in the original answer.

Comment: Yes, there is a screenshot in my question

Comment: Yes, I had a look at it and posted one from mine to confirm the configuration. I guess, there are some other modules/permissions overriding cart permissions.